# Pivotal Cloud Foundry vs OpenShift

Tags: comparison, openshift, cloud-foundry, paas

I'm looking for a PaaS solution and lately I've been looking into Pivotal Cloud Foundry and OpenShift Origin, trying to compare them.

And honestly, it feels like both offer pretty much the same functionality, to the point where I don't really see a thing, that is truly specific to one of them. 
They achieve different things differently, but the functionality remains the same.

The biggest difference seems to be the runtimes these technologies use, as OpenShift uses Kubernetes and PCF uses Diego, and PCF also has it's own container solution.

So here comes my question. What are the differences? 
Is there a killer feature in one of them that I'm missing?